# Как установить метрики (accuracy), где ошибка?

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, метрики

У меня проблема. Почему accuracy всегда показывает 100%. это ошибка.
Пересмотрел много информации и вроде сделал все по шаблону. но все равно 100%.
Взял стандартную нейросеть на Гитхабе для прогноза загрязнения в Пекине.(на ней обычно учатся)
Функция потерь работает хорошо.
А вот accuracy нет.
Как исправить?
Вот Код. (На многих сайтах он есть)
'''

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import concatenate
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM


# convert series to supervised learning
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j + 1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
        if i == 0:
            names += [('var%d(t)' % (j + 1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        else:
            names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j + 1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # put it all together
    agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    # drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg

# load dataset
dataset = read_csv('pollution.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = dataset.values
# integer encode direction
encoder = LabelEncoder()
values[:, 4] = encoder.fit_transform(values[:, 4])
# ensure all data is float
values = values.astype('float32')
# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
# frame as supervised learning
reframed = series_to_supervised(scaled, 1, 1)
# drop columns we don't want to predict
reframed.drop(reframed.columns[[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(reframed.head())

# split into train and test sets
values = reframed.values
n_train_hours = 365 * 24
train = values[:n_train_hours, :]
test = values[n_train_hours:, :]
# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)

# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=5, batch_size=54, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2)                    
train_acc = model.evaluate(train_X, train_y, verbose=2)
test_acc = model.evaluate(test_X, test_y, verbose=2)
# plot history
pyplot.subplot(211)
pyplot.title('Loss')
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.subplot(212)
pyplot.title('Accuracy')
pyplot.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
# make a prediction
yhat = model.predict(test_X)
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], test_X.shape[2]))
# invert scaling for forecast
inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, test_X[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:, 0]
# invert scaling for actual
test_y = test_y.reshape((len(test_y), 1))
inv_y = concatenate((test_y, test_X[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_y)
inv_y = inv_y[:, 0]
# calculate RMSE
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(inv_y, inv_yhat))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

'''
Все работает, кроме accuracy.
Чего не доделал не пойму.

Вот Взял другой пример.
данные разбиты по другому, но accuracy тоже 100%.
Почему так происходит?

'''

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset
dataframe = read_csv('proba2.csv')
dataset = dataframe.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))
# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict
# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict
# plot baseline and predictions
plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset))
plt.plot(trainPredictPlot)
plt.plot(testPredictPlot)
plt.show()
```

'''
'''

```
Epoch 96/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0153 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 97/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0156 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 98/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0156 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 99/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0153 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 100/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.0153 - accuracy: 1.0000
Train Score: 1.18 RMSE
Test Score: 1.18 RMSE
```

'''
Почему, не понятно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Epoch 1/5
 - 3s - loss: 0.0407 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0163 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2/5
 - 3s - loss: 0.0151 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0148 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 3/5
 - 3s - loss: 0.0145 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0146 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 4/5
 - 3s - loss: 0.0146 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0132 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 5/5
 - 3s - loss: 0.0144 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0132 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Comment: Обычно accuracy - 100% говорит об утечке данных. Т.е. в том случае, когда ваша модель уже видела тестовую выборку во время обучения. Убедитесь в том, что тестовая выборка не содержится в обучающей выборке

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Почитал пару статей, но честно говоря вообще не понял. Получается нужно разбить данные по другому. Так я понял или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, вы решаете задачу **регрессии**. Для неё метрика `accuracy` просто не имеет смысла. Можете почитать обсуждения [здесь](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7947) и [здесь](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/108).

Ну то есть `Keras` вроде как что-то даже считает и показывает. Но, как пишут в одном из этих обсуждений, в случае регрессии вы будете видеть в качестве `accuracy` какую-то константу всё время обучения, что у вас и происходит.

Метрика `accuracy` предназначена для задачи **классификации**, она показывает число сэмплов, для которых правильно определён **класс** объекта. В случае **регрессии** же вычисленные значения обычно бывают приблизительными, поэтому точные совпадения для неё считать бессмысленно. Если у вас действительно всё совершенно точно совпало, то вы просто идеально переобучились.

Comment: Да. Точно так и есть. Спасибо.